# Connecting the Pythagoras theorem to the ellipse equation

Tags: trigonometry

Given the right triangle with the point M at (x,y).

There's an ellipse that touches the point M, with the centre at 0,0. No matter where you place M.

The formula for it would be:

$x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$

According to Pythagoras theorem:

$(a+b)^2 = (x + b * cos ABC)^2 + (y + a * sin ABC)^2$

Can we obtain the ellipse equation from the Pythagoras theorem above?
[image]

Comment: I think you mean to require that the ellipse and $BC$ are tangent at $M$. Do you know how to represent or test tangents to an ellipse? (There's a way involving simple calculus and a way involving a "stretch" of the plane to make the ellipse a circle. Maybe others.)

Comment: Did you notice, if $a = b$ that $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$ becomes $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$. Isn't $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ the Pythagorean theorem, also the formula for a circle with center $(0, 0)$ and radius $a$?

Answer (score 1):

I think you over-specify your geometry, using $a$ and $b$ within 2 different places, once as parameters of your ellipsis, and further as the distances on the line.

$$ $$

None the less your setup, given a line and a point thereon, which shall define an origin-centered ellipsis, which is tangent to the line within the given point, is interesting.

So consider your points $A(0; 0)$, $B(n; 0)$, and $C(0; m)$, which define your triangle. Further consider the point $P(c;d)$ on the side $BC$.

Now assume that you have some ellipsis given by the implicit function
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-1=0$$
By means of the total derivative you generally can calculate the local inclination as
$$y'=-\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}=-\frac{\frac{2x}{a^2}}{\frac{2y}{b^2}}=-\frac{b^2x}{a^2y}$$
Therefore the local inclination at $P$ would become
$$y'=-\frac{b^2c}{a^2d}$$
Using the point-inclination form you can now derive the line $BC$ as
$$(y-d)=\left(-\frac{b^2c}{a^2d}\right)(x-c)$$
$$y=-\frac{b^2c}{a^2d}x+\frac{b^2c+a^2d}{a^2d}$$
This can be further simplified, using that $P$ is on the elllipsis, i.e.
$$1=\frac{c^2}{a^2}+\frac{d^2}{b^2}=\frac{b^2c+a^2d}{a^2b^2}$$
or simply $b^2c+a^2d=a^2b^2$. Hence one continues with that line $BC$:
$$y=-\frac{b^2c}{a^2d}x+\frac{a^2b^2}{a^2d}=-\frac{b^2c}{a^2d}x+\frac{b^2}d$$
When evaluating $BC$ at point $C(0;m)$ we get
$$m=-\frac{b^2c}{a^2d}0+\frac{b^2}d=\frac{b^2}d$$
and therefrom $b^2=md$.
When evaluating $BC$ at point $B(n;0)$ we get
$$0=-\frac{b^2c}{a^2d}n+\frac{b^2}d$$
$$n=\frac{\frac{b^2}d}{\frac{b^2c}{a^2d}}=\frac{a^2}c$$
and therefrom $a^2=nc$.

Thus finally our ellipsis parameters $a$ and $b$ have been derived from the given geometry of that line $BC$ and its point $P$ thereon.

--- rk